I have use flutter camera and capturing video of front camera and back camera then
I have use flutter camera and capturing video of front camera and back camera then after i see this video then android 11, 12 not showing video of front camera
After Capturing video successfully open video like front camera or back camera

There were OS issues 11 and 12 due to different permissions. There were issues 13 and 14 for full storage permission for the latest version.
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
final androidInfo = await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo;
if (androidInfo.version.sdkInt >= 32) {
  var status = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
  if (status.isGranted) {
    
  }
} else {
  var status = await Permission.storage.request();
  if (status.isGranted) {
   }}

